# Meaning of "of near-religious proportions"

Tags: meaning

What does "of near-religious proportions" mean in this sentence: "Gromyko's response evinced a belief in Marxism of near-religious proportions" (The Triumph of Improvisation p 85)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gromyko's response made people think that the strength ("proportions") of his (Gromyko's) belief in Marxism was nearly as great as, and of a similar nature to, the belief in God held by devout religious people.